# how to make tool bar transparent

Tags: android

I want to make my toolbar transparent but don't know how?
   `

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451605/make-toolbar-transparent

Answer (score 0):

All you need to is to define theme which hide action bar, define action bar style with transparent background and set this style to the toolbar widget. Please note that toolbar should be drawen as last view (over all view tree)

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```